# NSLog string is fine but string into UITextView causes exception

Tags: ios, objective-c, tfhpple

So I have a view controller and in the `viewdidload` method it's supposed to load some content from a webpage (just a proof of concept, it'll be cached eventually). It gets the content using the `tfhipple` library and puts the contents into an array, it logs the data to the console and then I want it to apply the contents to a `UITextView`. However when the view controller is called it gets so far as to log the text to the console but on the line where it sets it as the contents of the `UITextView` it causes an exception.

```
NSData *dataURL;
NSString *url = @"http://www.testwebsite.com/testpage.html";
dataURL =  [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: url]];

NSString *serverOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];

TFHpple * doc       = [[TFHpple alloc] initWithHTMLData:dataURL];

NSArray *elements  = [doc searchWithXPathQuery:@"//div[contains(@id,'main-section')]//text()"];

NSString * aboutcontents = [elements objectAtIndex:2];
NSLog(@"test: %@", aboutcontents);
self.aboutbox.text = aboutcontents;
```

The exception it causes is as follows, along with the console output before hand:

```
2013-06-24 09:37:51.433 AppName[24765:c07] test: {
    nodeContent = "Test Content";
    nodeName = text;
    raw = "Test Content";
}
2013-06-24 09:37:51.434 AppName[24765:c07] -[TFHppleElement length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8043be0
2013-06-24 09:37:51.434 AppName[24765:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[TFHppleElement length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8043be0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x25d012 0x16ebe7e 0x2e84bd 0x24cbbc 0x24c94e 0x76b4fb 0x3347 0x7111c7 0x711232 0x7328c9 0x732704 0x730bda 0x730a5c 0x732647 0x16ff705 0x6332c0 0x633258 0x855ff4 0x16ff705 0x6332c0 0x633258 0x6f4021 0x6f457f 0x6f4056 0x859af9 0x16ff705 0x6332c0 0x633258 0x6f4021 0x6f457f 0x6f36e8 0x662cef 0x662f02 0x640d4a 0x632698 0x22b2df9 0x22b2ad0 0x1d2bf5 0x1d2962 0x203bb6 0x202f44 0x202e1b 0x22b17e3 0x22b1668  0x62fffc 0x2fdd 0x21a5)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
(lldb)
```

I'm a little bit stuck as to why it does this. If I manually set the string `aboutcontents` to something then it changes the contents of the `UITextView` without issue.

Any help is as always appreciated.

Comment: `aboutcontents` is not an `NSString`, that is why it fails.  `NSLog` will call a method on `NSObject` so that is why it can still succeed.

Comment: Objects of the class TFHippleElement do not support the `length` selector.  Why are you sending a TFHippleElement to something that's expecting an NSString?

Comment: Try this self.aboutbox.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", aboutcontents]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you getting resutt for `NSString * aboutcontents = [elements objectAtIndex:2];` is a dictionary,convert dictionary into string like this

```
NSString * aboutcontents=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[elements objectAtIndex:2]];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
TFHppleElement * aboutcontents = [elements objectAtIndex:2];
NSLog(@"test: %@", [aboutcontents text]);
self.aboutbox.text = [aboutcontents text];
```

Here is the documentation part taken from [hpple](https://github.com/topfunky/hpple):

```
TFHppleElement * element = [elements objectAtIndex:0];
[e text];                       // The text inside the HTML element (the content of the  first text node)
[e tagName];                    // "a"
[e attributes];                 // NSDictionary of href, class, id, etc.
[e objectForKey:@"href"];       // Easy access to single attribute
[e firstChildWithTagName:@"b"]; // The first "b" child node
```

Try to get attributes for example and see what it returns to you.

Comment: fixed to calling text method

Comment: Hi, thanks, this doesn't cause a crash but it returns null.

Comment: If it returns null, that probably means there is no text in that particular element.  Try one of the keywords that appears in your log. @Adam

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
NSDictionary * aboutcontents = [elements objectAtIndex:2];
NSLog(@"test: %@", aboutcontents);
self.aboutbox.text = [aboutcontents objectForKey:@"nodeContent"];
```

I don't understand the context but I saw { } in the Log and I guess only dictionaries get printed that way.